# ¿Como hago para poner los valores que hay en 2 columnas en 1?

Tags: excel

Os comento mi problema.
Resulta que estoy haciendo un Excel que contabilice las alarmas que habrá en 1 año.

Para ello tengo una tabla con los meses de cada año, días, hora y código de cuando se produce la alarma.

Para un solo mes tengo sencillo hacer la tabla que podéis observar ahí.
Pues haciendo un filtrado avanzado me saca los valores, sin duplicados y sin espacios en blanco, pero si selecciono a parte de la columna de Cód alarma de septiembre, la columna de Cód alarma de octubre no me junta todo en una misma columna... ¿Cómo hago para juntar todo en la misma columna?

Sino me he explicado bien puedo aportar más información.
Un saludo,
Samuel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En resumen, quiero copiar los valores de cód alarma de septiembre, octubre, noviembre y diciembre y que me filtre tanto los duplicados como los textos vacíos. Luego el indicarle las veces que se repite ese texto ya se hacerlo, como su porcentaje. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme porque no soy muy experto en excel que digamos xD

Comment: Para juntar valores, mira CONCATENAR en Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y por qué no normalizas esa tabla donde recoges los datos y luego montas una tabla dinámica?

¿Algo así para empezar? Una tabla normalita y, a partir de ella, una dinámica:

[image: captura]

Comment: Esta solución es muy buena. Muchas gracias amigo ^^